# How do I get the values into my variables from the following regex PHP?

Tags: php, regex, file

I need to parse a big log file to get the ipadress, datetime, source and client from all the records.

The following link with the regex works:

http://regex101.com/r/cG9tY7

Regex:

```
(?<ipAddress>.*?)\s-\s-\s\[(?<dateTime>.*?)\]\s\"GET\s(?<source>.*?)\"\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\s\"-\"\s\"(?<client>.*?)\"
```

Maybe the format is not ok for PHP ?

I open the file as such:

```
$filename = "access-streaming_small.log"
$file = popen("tac $filename", 'r');
```

If I use :

```
while ($line = fgets($file)) {
echo $line;
}
```

I get the full log file which is displayed ok.

I need to process it with regex so that I get variables of ipadress, datetime, source and client from all records contained in the log file. 
Bonus task: I need to filter results to get the most current details of the records generated in the last 10 minutes compared to current time.

Comment: Bonus question: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your regex is good and should work with PHP. You have forgotten to put delimiters `$regex = '~(?<ipAddress.*?)....(?<client>.*?)"~';` (as an aside comment: no need to escape double quotes if you put your pattern between single quotes).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  I got it to work .. I just need to filter results now .. most recent in the past 10 mins of the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [preg_match](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)? Important are the 
'/ and /' else it won't work

`preg_match('/(?P<name>\w+): (?P<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches);`